# Reduce always return previous state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have a array of data:

```
const [callListData, setCallListData] = useState<{results: Array<CallDataInterface>;}>(serverData);
```

that is updating in a getData function (polling every 5sec, becouse user needs to see fresh data).
When user is scrolling down, more records are shown (increase page value for infinite scroll), so fetch request have a page param = page + 1. When user is scrolling up, the page is set to page - 1.
I have a problem with how I can update array that I already have and don't add duplicates to it (when user gets back to page 1 for example, there is still the same data - same Ids, but for example another value changes so it needs to refresh).
Right now i have:

```
if (prevActiveDate.current !== activeDate) {
            prevActiveDate.current = activeDate;
            setListData(response.data);
            setDataMap({});
          } else {
            const updatedDataMap = response.data.results.reduce(
              (
                accumulator: Record<string, DataInterface>,
                item: CallDataInterface
              ) => {
                if (!accumulator[item.data_id]) {
                  accumulator[item.data_id] = item; 
                }
                return accumulator;
              },
              { ...dataMap } 
            );
            setDataMap(updatedDataMap); 
            const newData = Object.values(updatedDataMap) as DataInterface[];
            setListData({ results: newData });
          }
```

And it works fine, but to problem is that when Im changing activeDate and for example response.data.results is empty array [], then after second fetch call its showing previous array ListData. How can I prevent that thing?

I tried setting ListData to empty array in every activeDate value change:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setListData({ results: [] });
    setDataMap({});
  }, [activeDate]);
```

but no success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.